# How Do I Fix My Code So It Can print() Out The Results I Want?

Tags: python, class, init, python-3.5

**Note: I'm not looking for you to remake my code, I'm looking for tips and links to sites that will help me improve this code. If you want to fix the code I will also accept your answer.**

I'm trying to understand how `class` works but, I'm having a really hard time doing so. I made a `class` called `Stat` which contains all of the stats for a given user. All of the stats for the user are, `name, level, totexp and role`. each `role` has 3 stats (it should have three but, my code is messed up), `health, attack, and defense`. Here is the main code (not working):

```
class Stat():
    def __init__(self, name, level, totexp, role, health, attack, defense):
        self.name = Name
        self.level = 1
        self.totexp = 0
        self.role = Role
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.exp = 0
def choose_name():
    while(True):
        Name = input("What is your Dicer's name?:\n").title()
        if(any(Bad_Words in Name.lower() for Bad_Words in [])):
            print("That's an inappropriate name! Try again")
        elif(len(Name) < 3):
            print("That name is too short! Try again.")
        elif(len(Name) > 16):
            print("That name is too long! Try again.")
        else:
            break
def choose_role():
    Roles = {
   'mage':lambda:Role(100, 40, 10), #(Health, Attack, Defense)
   'warrior':lambda:Role(100, 30, 20),
   'gunner':lambda:Role(100, 20, 30),
   'archer':lambda:Role(100, 10, 40)
   }
    while(True):
        Role = input("What role do you want to be?\nChoices:\n1. Mage\n"
                     "2. Warrior\n3. Gunner\n4. Archer\n").title()
        if(Role.lower() in (Roles)):
            return
        else:
            print("That's not a role! Try again.")
self = choose_name()
self = choose_role()
```

After the main code the `Results` (Like in the title) or the result code should `print` out the `Stats` accordingly to the order of the instances. Here is the result code:

```
print("Here is your Dicer's information:\nDicer's name: {0}\n"
      "Level: {1}\nExperience: {2}\nRole: {3}\nRole Stats:\n"
      "Health: {4}\nAttack: {5}\nDefense: {6}".format(self.name, self.level,
                                                      self.totexp, self.role,
                                                      self.health, self.attack,
                                                      self.defense))
```

When I run the code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 37, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I think I have ideas to why this is happening but I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me with where I need to start on with my code and ways to fix it. Here is the results I wanted (For this example the Name = Bob and Role = Gunner):

```
Dicer's name: Bob
Level: 1
Experience: 0
Role: Gunner
Role Stats:
Health: 100
Attack: 20
Defense: 30
```

Comment: Your error is on line 50 but the code you put is only 36 lines. Anyway inside your stat fix both of these (your capitalization was messed up). You should use `self.name = name` and `self.role = role`

Comment: @Keatinge Where do I put these? I assume you mean outside of `class` but I truly don't know.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalist. Inside the stat class you have the line `self.name = Name` replace it with `self.name = name` and likewise for self.role. **Python is case sensitive**

Comment: the very bottom of your code you do `self = choose_name() ; self = choose_role()` but both of those functions return `None` so the global variable `self` will be equal to `None`.  You do not create any `Stat` objects.

Comment: @Keatinge The reason I did it that way is because `Name = input(...)` and so the what the user types in should've in turn been = self.name

Comment: `self = choose_name()` assigns the value `None` to `self` because the function doesn't return anything. `self = choose_role()` has a similar problem. You need to create an instance of your class, i.e. `stat = Stat(... __init__ arguments ...)`, then you can reference attributes with `stat.name` and `stat.role`. Also don't name a variable `self`, because, by convention, that is only used as the name of the first argument to a class method — but your class doesn't have any defined.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for helping clarify things up. I'm really bad with `class` and I'm kinda learning the ropes.

Comment: Brad: You're welcome. The best way to learn is by trying...which usually involves some trial-and-error (as well as doing research and asking questions here if all else fails).

Comment: @Keatinge I'm so happy! I just upgraded my code with help. https://repl.it/C0OS/115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little hesitant to post this because the code is a giant mess. But you said you didn't want a re-write you just wanted to see your code fixed, so here it is fixed. I've commented everything I changed

```
#renamed stat to player, the point of the object shouldn't be to hold just the stats, should hold all information
#pertaining to the player / dicer
class Dicer():
    #levelm, totalexp, health removed from constructor
    def __init__(self, name, role, health, attack, defense):
        self.name = name #changed Name to name
        self.level = 1
        self.totexp = 0
        self.role = role #changed Role to role
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.exp = 0

    #instance function to print the stats of the dicer
    def print_info(self):
        print(
            "Here is your Dicer's information:\nDicer's name: {0}\nLevel: {1}\nExperience: {2}\nRole:"\
            " {3}\nRole Stats:\nHealth: {4}\nAttack: {5}\nDefense: {6}".format(self.name, self.level, self.totexp, self.role, self.health, self.attack, self.defense)
        )
def choose_name():
    while(True):
        Name = input("What is your Dicer's name?:\n").title()
        if(any(Bad_Words in Name.lower() for Bad_Words in [])):
            print("That's an inappropriate name! Try again")
        elif(len(Name) < 3):
            print("That name is too short! Try again.")
        elif(len(Name) > 16):
            print("That name is too long! Try again.")
        else:
            #you have to return the name so you can use it later
            return Name

def choose_role():
    #removed all the lambdas here
    Roles = {
   'mage': (100, 40, 10), #(Health, Attack, Defense)
   'warrior': (100, 30, 20),
   'gunner': (100, 20, 30),
   'archer': (100, 10, 40)
   }

    while(True):
        Role = input("What role do you want to be?\nChoices:\n1. Mage\n2. Warrior\n3. Gunner\n4. Archer\n").title()
        if(Role.lower() in (Roles)):
            #don't just return None, return the name of the role and it's 3-tuple stats
            #returning the role and it's stats from a function is not the best way to do this
            return Role, Roles[Role.lower()]
        else:
            print("That's not a role! Try again.")

dicer_name = choose_name()
dicer_role_name, dicer_role_stats = choose_role()

#create a dicer using the stats returned from chose_role() function
mainDicer = Dicer(dicer_name, dicer_role_name, dicer_role_stats[0], dicer_role_stats[1], dicer_role_stats[2])
mainDicer.print_info()
```

Here is how I would do it if writing it from scratch

```
class Dicer():
    def __init__(self, name, role, statTuple):
        self.name = name
        self.level = 1
        self.xp = 0
        self.health = statTuple[0]
        self.attack = statTuple[1]
        self.defense = statTuple[2]

    def print_stats(self):
        print("Name", self.name)
        print("Level", self.level)
        print("XP", self.xp)
        print("Health", self.health)
        print("Attack", self.attack)
        print("Defense", self.defense)


roles = {
    #health, attack defense
    "mage" : (100, 40, 10),
    "warrior" : (100, 30, 20),
    "gunner" : (100, 20, 30),
    "archer" : (100, 10, 40)
}
name = input("What is your name ")
dicer_role_choice = None
while dicer_role_choice not in roles.keys():
    print("Please select a dicer:")

    #prints each role on a new line, showing all the possible choices
    print("\n".join(roles.keys()))
    dicer_role_choice = input()

mainDicer = Dicer(name, dicer_role_choice, roles[dicer_role_choice])
mainDicer.print_stats()
```

Comment: I'm suprised the code didn't need to be remade. I'm glad you new what was wrong with it.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist I mean it really should be remade though. You've written all the logic and I just duct taped the whole thing together

Comment: Yeah I'm so bad with `class` I usually do just def() functions because I'm most familiar with them.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist I'll update the question in a few minutes showing you how you could do this most optimally, obviously you don't need to use it

Comment: Do So I'm sure it will help me.

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist statTuple contains the 3 values for the selected role. So if you chose mage it would be: `(100, 40, 10)`. Then you pass that tuple into the Dicer constructor, there it assigns the first element to health, second element to attack, third element to defense

Comment: so does roles[dicer_role_choice] connect the two?

Comment: Sorta, that line looks up the correct tuple for the selected role that the user  types in.

Comment: For this game, I have to put moves, creatures, and a level system in the game which is going to be difficult.

Comment: I'm not asking for help I'm just saying that's were the game is going

Answer (score 0):

I revamped my code here it is:

Code provider: Bradley Elko

Update 1 [51 lines]

Update 2 [97 lines]

Update 3 [127 lines]

Update 4 [148 lines]

---

```
class Char():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.role = ""
        self.health = 0
        self.health_now = 0
        self.health_gained = 0
        self.attack = 0
        self.defense = 0
        self.glob()
        self.add_name()
        self.add_role()
        self.print_info()
        self.menu()
    def glob(self):
        global Level, TotXp, Xp, Info, Points
        Level = 1
        Points = 15
        TotXp = 0
        Xp = 0
        Info = "Not Filled In Yet"
    def print_info(self):
        print("\nYour Character's Stats:")
        print("Your character's name is: {0}".format(self.name))
        print("Your character is level: {0}".format(Level))
        print("You have {0} Level Points\n".format(Points))
        print("Your Role Stats:")
        print("Your character's role is: {0}\nYour character's health is: {1}\nYour character's attack is: {2}\nYour character's defense is: {3}".format(self.role, self.health, self.attack, self.defense))
        print("\nIntroduction To Game:\n{0}".format(Info))
    def add_name(self):
        while(True):
            Name = input("What's your character's name?\n")
            if(len(Name) < 3):
                print("That name is too short!")
            elif(len(Name) > 20):
                print("That name is too long!")
            elif(any(bad_word in Name.lower() for bad_word in ['fuck'])):
                print("That name is inappropriate!")
            else:
                self.name += Name
                break
    def add_role(self):
        global Role
        Roles = {
        "Marksman": (100, 50, 30),
        "Melee":(100, 40, 40),
        "Mage":(100, 30, 50)
        }
        while(True):
            Role = input("\nWhat's your characters role?\nChoices:\n1. Marksman\n2. Melee\n3. Mage\n").title()
            if(Role not in ['Marksman', 'Melee', 'Mage']):
                print("That's not a role!")
            else:
                self.role += Role
                self.health += Roles[Role][0]
                self.health_now += Roles[Role][0]
                self.attack += Roles[Role][1]
                self.defense += Roles[Role][2]
                break
    def menu(self):
        global Choice
        print("\nMenu\nWelcome to the menu! Here is where you will be staying in between fights, regaining health, and using the shop.\n")
        while(True):
            Choice = input("Where do you want to go?\n1. Shop\n2. Fight\n3. Sleep\n4. Role Stats\n5. Char Stats\n").lower()
            if(Choice == "shop"):
                return self.shop()
            elif(Choice == "fight"):
                print("Needing updating!")
                break
            elif(Choice == "sleep"):
                self.sleeping()
                break
            elif(Choice == "role stats"):
                return self.role_stats()
            elif(Choice == "char stats"):
                return self.char_stats()
            else:
                print("That's not an option!")
    def menu_two(self):
        global Choice
        print("\nMenu\nWelcome back to the menu!")
        while(True):
            Choice = input("Where do you want to go next?\n1. Shop\n2. Fight\n3. Sleep\n4. Role Stats\n5. Char Stats\n").lower()
            if(Choice == "shop"):
                return self.shop()
            elif(Choice == "fight"):
                print("Needing updating!")
                break
            elif(Choice == "sleep"):
                self.sleeping()
                break
            elif(Choice == "role stats"):
                return self.role_stats()
            elif(Choice == "char stats"):
                return self.char_stats()
            else:
                print("That's not an option!")
    def role_stats(self):
        global Choice
        if(Choice == "role stats"):
            print("\nRole Stats:\nRole: {0}\nHealth: {1}\nAttack: {2}\nDefense: {3}\n".format(self.role, self.health, self.attack, self.defense))
            return self.menu_two()
    def shop(self):
        while(True):
            Buy = input("\nWelcome to the shop! Here is were you spend your level points. What do you want to purchase?\nChoices:\n1. Abilities\n2. Weapons\n3. Stat Points\n4. Nothing\n").lower()
            if(Buy == "abilities"):
                print("\nYou selected 'Abilities'.")
                break
            elif(Buy == "weapon"):
                print("\nYou selected 'Weapons'.")
                break
            elif(Buy == "stat points"):
                print("\nYou selected 'Stat Points'.")
                break
            elif(Buy == "nothing"):
                print("\nReturning to menu...")
                return self.menu_two()
            else:
                print("\nThat is not an option!")
    def char_stats(self):
        global Choice
        if(Choice == "char stats"):
            print("\nYour Character's Stats:")
            print("Username: {0}".format(self.name))
            print("Level: {0}".format(Level))
            print("Level Points: {0}".format(Points))
            return self.menu_two()
    def sleeping(self):
        global Choice
        import time
        if(Choice == "sleep" and self.health_now >= self.health):
            print("\nYour health is full and so you don't need to sleep. Returning to menu.")
            return self.menu_two()
        elif(Choice =="sleep" and self.health_now < self.health):
            print("\nYou are sleeping to regain health. This doubles your characters health regeneration! Please wait patently as your character sleeps to regain health faster.")
            for i in range(1, 1801):
                time.sleep(1)
                if(i in [60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540,600,660,720,780,840,900,960,1020,1080,1140,1200,1260,1320,1380,1440,1500,1560,1620,1680,1740,1800]):
                    self.health_gained += 10
                    self.health_now += 10
                    if(self.health_now < self.health):
                        print("\nYou're still healing. You've regained %d health!\nCurrent health:\nHealth: %d/%d" % (self.health_gained, self.health_now, self.health))
                    else:
                        print("\nYou're done healing! You've regained %d health!\nCurrent health:\nHealth: %d/%d" % (self.health_gained - (self.health_now - self.health), self.health, self.health))
                        print("\nYou woke up from your healing nap. Returning to menu.")
                        return self.menu_two()
                    self.health_gained -= 10
MyChar = Char()
```

---

Update 1 Date [6/10/2016]

Update 2 Date [6/10/2016]

Update 3 Date [6/11/2016]

Update 4 Date [6/14/2016]

Link 1: https://repl.it/C0gh/46

Link 2: https://repl.it/C0gh/60

Link 3: https://repl.it/C0gh/79